# windows 8.1 scheduled tasks fail to run

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-task-scheduler

I have several scheduled tasks that were running for months now. Suddenly 3 days ago, they all fail.

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Date:          9/11/2014 2:28:52 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Task Start Failed
Level:         Error
Keywords:      (1)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      BD1
Description:
Task Scheduler failed to start "\Bxxxx\daily log email" task for user "BD1\Dan". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler" Guid="{DE7B24EA-73C8-4A09-985D-5BDADCFA9017}" />
    <EventID>101</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>101</Task>
    <Opcode>101</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-11T11:28:52.102519800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>345269</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="780" ThreadID="15448" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>BD1</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData Name="TaskStartFailedEvent">
    <Data Name="TaskName">\Bxxxx\daily log email</Data>
    <Data Name="UserContext">BD1\Dan</Data>
    <Data Name="ResultCode">2147943726</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

and

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Date:          9/11/2014 3:14:24 AM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Task Start Failed
Level:         Error
Keywords:      (1)
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      BD1
Description:
Task Scheduler failed to start "\Bxxxx\DAN delete old security files" task for user "BD1\Dan". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler" Guid="{DE7B24EA-73C8-4A09-985D-5BDADCFA9017}" />
    <EventID>101</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>101</Task>
    <Opcode>101</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-11T00:14:24.458719600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>344309</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="780" ThreadID="12528" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>BD1</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData Name="TaskStartFailedEvent">
    <Data Name="TaskName">\Bardov\DAN delete old security files</Data>
    <Data Name="UserContext">BD1\Dan</Data>
    <Data Name="ResultCode">2147943726</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

User Dan is logged in, and is an Administrator.

Any help would be nice

Answer (score 4):

#### Task Scheduler failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726

This error (according to the discussion in the link) appears to be password related.

If you have recently changed your password then you need to make the same change in the properties for the scheduled task:

- Click the "Change user or Group" button
- Enter the **same** account name and click "OK".
- Click "OK" on the task properties
- You should be prompted to enter the **new** account password.

Note:

- You have to choose "Run whether user is logged on or not" in the "Security Options" section in order to set the password.

Source [Task Scheduler failed to start. Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943726. What does this mean?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/task-scheduler-failed-to-start-additional-data/96994b77-d690-4403-8b51-4e1d0ae998e1)